# Do cronjobs run in CLI?

Tags: php, centos-6, cronjob, php-extensions

I am running PHP 5.5 with ZendOPcache integrated. There are two options for this extension - is cache enabled (which I've set to true), and the second one - is CLI cache enabled, which I've set to false.
I am wondering if cronjobs run in CLI, because if they don't, it's a problem for my cronjobs, because they are sync tasks and have to read the latest content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron jobs can run either via CLI or through the webserver - depending on how you set them up.

- If you run `[/path/to/]php --some-options -f /path/to/script` or similar you chose the CLI version
- If you run `[wget|curl] 'http://localhost/some/thing.php'` or similar you chose to run inside the webserver

Both versions have their pros and cons, but the important bit is: You have the choice.